# How to use forced alignment in windows (python)?

Tags: python, windows, text-alignment

I'm wanting to create a application using forced alignment in windows using python 3.11. The problem is that I cannot find any forced alignment package for windows.

I tried aeneas but couldn't figure out how to install it. If someone could tell me how to install aeneas for python 3.11 in windows I would he grateful.

I also tried using gentle but same problem not available for windows. It does have docker but to use docker I need to enable WSL which consumes so much ram and so much CPU that it's almost impossible to use.

Any way for me to complete my project using a python library which has forced alignment?

I tried using gentle and aeneas but couldn't figure out how to download them for python 3.11 in windows

Comment: Montreal Forced Aligner supposedly works on Windows (though personally I went the WSL/Docker route when I used it): https://montreal-forced-aligner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-via-pip

Comment: @slothrop Thanks for the suggestion I just had a few questions. How accurate is it? I'm building something user-facing. It looks quite complex to use any resource which will help me understand Montreal better? Or should I just read the docs?

Comment: So in my case I was working with audio that was (a) quite poor in recording quality, (b) had lots of background sound and interruptions. In that context, I found MFA was useful but the results had to be manually edited afterwards - it was better than doing everything manually, but a long way from perfect. With better quality audio I guess it would have worked better.

Comment: Regarding documentation, I used the docs online and some tutorials linked from them. But then I didn't try anything complex like training my own model or dictionary.

Comment: All that said, aeneas does supposedly work with Windows, so if that's your preferred tool and you have problems installing it, maybe post a question with your specific problems?

Comment: @slothrop How would I go about performing a simple task? Like i have a tts wav file and the transcipt of that tts. I need the mappings of each sentence of that transcript. I'm quite bad at explaining sorry for that. Aeneas does work for windows but for that i need to use python 2.7 Which is something i'm not looking forward to

Comment: So a simple alignment task follows these steps in the CLI: https://montreal-forced-aligner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first_steps/index.html#aligning-a-speech-corpus-with-existing-pronunciation-dictionary-and-acoustic-model. However, it's going to need some massaging of the input and output formats. Input text should be a Prosodylab file (explained here: https://montreal-forced-aligner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/corpus_structure.html#prosodylab-aligner-format). And output will be a Praat TextGrid, so if you want a CSV then it needs something like https://github.com/kylerbrown/textgrid

Comment: Sorry I don't have a really clean answer, I would also like to know if someone has a smooth workflow for this in Windows!

Comment: There's a list of tools here, but unfortunately doesn't say which work in Windows: https://github.com/pettarin/forced-alignment-tools#programs-and-libraries